# In IdentityServer4 how does the Google middleware handle the /signin-google callback after successful authentication?

Tags: identityserver4, google-authentication

I am using IdentityServer4. I have configured Google authentication middleware as seen [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Startup.cs#L38). However, the redirect uri registered with Google is `<domain>/signin-google`. Additionally, I know that the [ExternalLoginCallback](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L202) endpoint gets called after I have authenticated with Google and after the redirect uri that is registered with Google has been called (`/signin-google`).

My question is what happens between `/signin-google` and the call to `/ExternalLoginCallback`? What method(s) in the Google middleware are triggered once the browser is redirected to `/signin-google` but before the application/middleware eventually makes it to `/ExternalLoginCallback`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [ASP.NET Core Security Github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/23da47617624cfed065cd1cdd552d34e5ea5b821) you can find the implementation of the [Google middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/23da47617624cfed065cd1cdd552d34e5ea5b821/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google). Essentially, if you trace through the code you will see the `GoogleHandler` inherits from `OAuthHandler<T>` which inherits from `RemoteAuthenticationHandler<T>`. In `RemoteAuthenticationHandler<T>` you will see a method called `ShouldHandleRequestAsync` ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/23da47617624cfed065cd1cdd552d34e5ea5b821/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L40)). This method checks the current URL versus the URL that is on the `CallbackPath` property on the `Options` object. This is how the authentication middleware is triggered after the redirect back from the authentication provider - it's handled by the middleware - NOT a controller. Once the middleware is triggered it resumes the authentication process.

All external authentication provider middleware works this way. Once the middleware is triggered a method called called `HandleRemoteAuthentication` in OAuthHandler is triggered. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/23da47617624cfed065cd1cdd552d34e5ea5b821/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs#L45). This triggers the second leg of the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow process](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) where the one time use code obtained in the first leg of the process is exchanged for an access token. That process happens before the ExternalLoginCallback is triggered. Specifically, once the code has been exchanged for an access token and some user information is obtained from Google a `ClaimsPrincipal` is created and a temporary cookie is issued. By default the cookie is named `idsrv.external`. Then, as you can see in the [IdentityServer4 Quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples) projects, the [ExternalLoginCallback](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L202) endpoint is triggered, the `idsrv.external` cookie is deleted and a new authentication cookie is issued for the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

The Google middleware overrides functionality from the base classes that is specific to Google, but essentially all of the OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect middleware works this way.